# How to add blog in default WordPress post type for SEO standard rule?

Tags: seo

I want to this structure in default post type.

Archive Page ( Blog page ) - domain/blog

- pagination link - domain/blog/page/2

Taxonomy page - domain/blog/taxonomy-slug

- pagination link - domain/blog/taxonomy-slug/page/2

Single page - domain/blog/posttitle

Comment: There’s no SEO “rule” that says URLs *must* be structured like this. The only difference to the default anyway is that the default requires the taxonomy name in the URL. Is this a problem?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, This is no problem. We can add blog word so SEO related algorithm. so we need this.